# ERROR WSREP`: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379:` Failed to open channel 'test_cluster'

Tags: mariadb, galera, ndbcluster

I have three server that I want to Install Galera clustering on them, I followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04-servers) to install and config it. but when I want to start the first server I got this error :

```
root@node107:/home/debian# service mysql start --wsrep-new-clusterping 
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

and :

```
root@node107:/home/debian# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Tue 2016-03-01 19:02:04 IRST, end at Tue 2016-03-01 19:39:32 IRST. --
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:31 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379: Failed to open channel 'test_cluster' at 'gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.11
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:31 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:31 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117) failed: 7
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:31 [ERROR] Aborting
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 
Mar 01 19:39:31 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:31 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
Mar 01 19:39:32 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:32 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
Mar 01 19:39:32 node107 mysqld[5102]: 160301 19:39:32 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Mar 01 19:39:32 node107 mysqld[5102]: 
Mar 01 19:39:32 node107 mysqld_safe[5378]: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

these are configuration file for the three servers :

`vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/cluster.cnf`

**Server1 :**

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
#wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=32G"

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117"
#wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107"

# Galera Synchronization Congifuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=user:pass

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.120.107"
wsrep_node_name="node107"
```

**Server 2:**

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
#wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=32G"

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107"
#wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117"

# Galera Synchronization Congifuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=user:pass

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.120.111"
wsrep_node_name="node111"
```

**server 3 :**

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
#wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=32G"

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117"

# Galera Synchronization Congifuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=user:pass

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.120.117"
wsrep_node_name="node117"
```

I don't understand what I have missed. what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should start the first node without below parameter in `my.cnf` :
    wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117"

Then start the other nodes normally :

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The first node should start normally like the others.

Answer (score 4):

Please bootstrap the first node with below option

```
service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

Make sure you have the settings below in all config files:

```
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.120.107,192.168.120.111,192.168.120.117"
```

Then start the other nodes using `service mysql start`

Both nodes will sync with bootstrap node.